# Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) Recommended to Use Custom MAIL FROM or Keep Amazonses.com?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

Just looking for recommendations on best practices for Amazon SES setup.  I mainly use it for transactional emails and I was wondering what the best practice is or what the pros and cons are for using the default MAIL FROM which sends from amazonses.com or if it's better to use a custom MAIL FROM in my domain or a subdomain.  Any recommendations?

Comment: We can't really answer this for you.  What are your business requirements?  Are you ok with email coming from you but not from your domain?  If it was a bank they'd say no - the email must come from their domain.  If it's a tiny startup with beta software and two customers then I'd say it doesn't matter.

Comment: The goal is to improve delivery to people's inboxes and less ending up in spam.  The reply-to is from our domain, it's just that the sender is from amazonses.com and thus relies on AWS SES's SPF, DKIM, and DMARC setup.  So I am basically wondering what benefits I might have with us in control of that.

Comment: If you're looking to improve delivery then your best bet is to set up your domain with proper SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records.  These records will be setup with `amazonses.com` either way but that is what really drives deliverability.

Comment: @stdunbar Do you advise that I use a subdomain, such as marketing.mydomain.com, to send marketing emails through versus my root domain?

Comment: Overall in my experience you're starting in the right place - using SES to send.  I use my main domain for my emails via SES.  I also have Lambda's that are sent SES events via SNS so that I can keep track of things like spam reports and bounces.  Mostly those are used to mark an address as unsubscribed.  Historically I've used Sendgrid too but liked having everything in one place.

Comment: @stdunbar one last question - I've added the custom MAIL FROM to Amazon SES and set up the DNS records.  Do I need to now change the "Source" value in my SendEmailCommand to now use an address in the subdomain?